# Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message keeps coming during editing a profile information

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel. I am trying to edit my use profile information but keep getting this error.
Can anyone pleas help me??

userController file:

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'Name' => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z._\s]+$/|max:20',

        ]);
        //validate dept and reg_no if profession=student
        $user->name = $request->input('Name');

         $user->save();
        return redirect()->route('user.show', $user->id);
    }
```

Edit_Profile file:

```
 <form action="{{route('user.update', Auth::user())}}" method="POST">
            @method('PUT')
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="Name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-left">Name*</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input id="Name" type="text" class="form-control" name="Name" value="{{Auth::user()->name}}">
                    </div>
                </div>
</form>
```

route file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::post('/profile','userController@update_avtr');
Route::resource('/user', 'userController');
```

Comment: try with php artisan cache:clear as first try, than if the errors continue to occur, let me know, and also post the entire routes file and the entire view

Comment: Do you have something conflicting with Route::resource('/user', 'userController'); ? this should be workig

Comment: I cleared my cache but doesn't work.. @AlbertoSinigaglia

Comment: Updated the route list..Is there any conflict in my route? @GiovanniS

Answer (score 0):

Change the place of `User $user` with `Request $request`:

`public function update(User $user, Request $request)`

and change form tag to this:

```
<form action="{{route('user.update', Auth::user()->id)}}" method="POST">
```

Comment: Does it recognize the route when you make it like this?
`public function update(User $user)`

Comment: use this: `<form action="{{route('user.update', Auth::user()->id)}}" method="POST">`

Comment: still showing the same error.. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: try to clear routes cache `php artisan route:clear` and then check your routes to see if it's correct `php artisan route:list`

Comment: i did check but nothing wrong i guess..actually used this in another project but now it is not working :/

Comment: i guess that this happens because there is no user authenticated(?) please check the page source and see what is the action of that form that has generated laravel

Comment: High probability

Comment: <form action="http://localhost:8000/user/1" method="POST"> this shows in the action of that form

Comment: send the response from `php artisan route:list`

Comment: sorry,,I didn't understand what you said @Hossein Jabbari

Comment: Put the output of the command in my last comment inside your question so I can see what's going on in your routes.